# add og:image in Wordpress Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress

So I create a new post in Wordpress.

I use the Gutenberg image block to upload an image.

When I scrape the post at the Facebook sharing debugger it displays another random image from my library and tells me no `og:image` is set.

There's only one image -- how to add the `og:image` tag?

Answer (score 1):

The `og:image` tag will contain only the "featured image" of your WP post. If there is no featured image,  social media sites will probably use/display the first "regular" image appearing in your post, but there's no guarantee for that.

You might want to use the "Yoast" plugin, this will most likely try to achieve this automatically.